# setting background color to entire page when fixed positioned divs are present

Tags: html, css

I have a solution where I have to pop up a custom modal message box for my site. When the modal popup is shown, I have to set color and opacity to the complete page so that the modal popup sticks out. 
I inject the below css class to the body tag to do this.

```
.fade_background
{
    background-color: black;
     opacity: 0.65;
}
```

It works for all elements in the page except for the elements which has a fixed position/absolute. I know that the fixed position element has the viewport as parent.

Any idea how can I target fixed position elements too.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example using Embeded StackOverflow Snippet or at best JSFiddle (or put your code online elsewhere) so we could test it? It's really hard to tell what's going wrong without being able to see your code.

Comment: Lookup their z-index css attribute

Comment: It's better to reorganize your DOM instead of z-index if possible

Answer (score 0):

Without viewing all elements, it is kind of hard to solve. But in basic lines, I would try to make certain that the elements are as absolute position with z-index below the overlay to highlight the modal window. It would be interesting that you publish the html and css, so I easily solve the issue.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not abuse the answer system. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the fixed and absolute positions have the same class as the rest of them. Also try and check to see if there are any other css styles that are overwriting .fade_background